# How to interpret fancy for loop in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

How does this line look as a regular 'for' loop?

```
inputList = [int(a) for a in inputList]
```

What are the advantages to writing a 'for' loop this way as opposed to the more vanilla way?

Comment: You define "fancy" one of the most common Python construct, that is explained at the beginning of every Python tutorial...https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: It's actually called 'list comprehension.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_list = []
for a in inputList:
    new_list.append(int(a))
inputList = new_list
```

Probably something like this.

Comment: I got an error: 

"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'inputList' referenced before assignment"

Comment: that's because inputList wasn't defined when it entered the for loop. It must be defined first

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about Python syntax which is known as list comprehension. Check out this [link](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

See the following example:

**No list comprehension:**

```
list = []
for i in range (0, 9):
    if i > 5:
        list.append(i)
```

*Output:* `[6, 7, 8]`

**List comprehension:**

```
newList = [i for i in list if i>=5]
```

*Output:* `[6, 7, 8]`

**Why use list comprehension**

List comprehension compressed 4 lines of code into 1 line of code

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this and it worked:

```
      enteredList = []
      for a in inputList:
          enteredList.append(int(a))
```